# How can I tell a UIGestureRecognizer to cancel an existing touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` I am using to track an object (`UIImageView`) below a user's finger. I only care about motion on the X axis, and if the touch strays above or below the object's frame on the Y axis I want to end the touch.

I've got everything I need for determining if a touch is within the object's Y bounds, but I don't know how to cancel the touch event. Flipping the recognizer's `cancelsTouchesInView` property doesn't seem to do what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 163):

This little trick works for me.

```
@implementation UIGestureRecognizer (Cancel)

- (void)cancel {
    self.enabled = NO;
    self.enabled = YES;
}

@end
```

From the `UIGestureRecognizer @enabled` documentation:

> Disables a gesture recognizers so it
>   does not receive touches. The default
>   value is YES. If you change this
>   property to NO while a gesture
>   recognizer is currently recognizing a
>   gesture, the gesture recognizer
>   transitions to a cancelled state.

Comment: OP appears to be asking about cancelling an individual touch within the gesture, not killing the gesture altogether.

Comment: Nice minimal solution

Comment: This technique is recommended in [WWDC 2014 Session 235: Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=235).

Comment: This will invoke UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled right after UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan and terminate that pan gesture.

Answer (score 15):

@matej's answer in Swift.

```
extension UIGestureRecognizer {
  func cancel() {
    isEnabled = false
    isEnabled = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful - no subclassing needed

Answer (score 11):

Obj-C:

```
recognizer.enabled = NO;
recognizer.enabled = YES;
```

Swift 3:

```
recognizer.isEnabled = false
recognizer.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this from the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
```

Disables a gesture recognizers so it does not receive touches. The default value is YES. If you change this property to NO while a gesture recognizer is currently recognizing a gesture, the gesture recognizer transitions to a cancelled state.

Answer (score 4):

Just set `recognizer.state` in your `handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)` method to `.ended` or `.cancelled`

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you can subclass you gesture recogniser:

In YourPanGestureRecognizer.m:

```
#import "YourPanGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation YourPanGestureRecognizer

- (void) cancelGesture {
    self.state=UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
}

@end
```

In YourPanGestureRecognizer.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface NPPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer

- (void) cancelGesture;

@end
```

Now you can call if from anywhere

```
YourPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[YourPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panMoved:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[...]
-(void) panMoved:(YourPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    [sender cancelGesture]; // This will be called twice
}
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple ways of handling this:

1. If you were writing a custom pan gesture recognizer subclass, you could easily do this by calling `-ignoreTouch:withEvent:` from inside the recognizer when you notice it straying from the area you care about.
2. Since you're using the standard Pan recognizer, and the touch *starts off* OK (so you don't want to prevent it with the delegate functions), you really can only make your distinction when you receive the recognizer's target actions. Check the Y value of the `translationInView:` or `locationInView:` return values, and clamp it appropriately.

Comment: the question is that how do you ignore the recognizer and pass touch events to others in its action?