# Autoscroll smoothly UITableView while dragging UITableViewCells in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I have implemented a system to reorder cells in my UITableViews. Everything is ok except that I can't reorder cells to a position that is not being showed in the iPhone screen.

So I have implemented a condition to check if I have to scroll

```
NSArray *indexVisibles = [_tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSInteger indexForObject = [indexVisibles indexOfObject:indexPath];
if (indexForObject == NSNotFound){
     [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                                  animated:YES];
}
```

My problem is that the animation is not sweet and clean.

[image]

I think that the operation of checking if a cell is showed is very huge for my system and make a small delay when I move cells, but also, I'm not sure why the scroll is so hard when the cell is hide.

I have change `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` to `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle` and now it is better but the velocity is very big so always scroll goes to the top of my UITableView.

I would like to do it slowly.

**Other failure tries:**

Option 1:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                             animations:^{_tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, _tableView.contentOffset.y - 50);}
                                             completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
```

But this has got two problems:

1. Movement is still heavy
2. When drag to the first element, this element is middle hide

[image]

Option 2:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                                             animations: ^{
                                                 [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                                                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                                                           animated:NO];
                                             }completion: ^(BOOL finished){

                                             }
                             ];
```

Comment: Please check this repository hope this is work for you.
https://github.com/hpique/HPReorderTableView

Comment: It seems to be right but it has got some bugs and it is not applicable to my project. But I'm studying your code to find the error and fix them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved my problem with a very beautiful solution so I'm going to explain in three simple steps how to do it.

I have use some inspiration from https://github.com/hpique/HPReorderTableView and share it in my own repository https://github.com/enrimr/EMRReorderTableCells

**A. Manage gestureRecognition**

***longPressGestureRecognized:***

```
- (IBAction)longPressGestureRecognized:(id)sender {

    _reorderGestureRecognizer = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    CGPoint location = [_reorderGestureRecognizer locationInView:_tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self getCellIndexPathWithPoint:location];

    UIGestureRecognizerState state = _reorderGestureRecognizer.state;
    switch (state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
            if (indexPath == nil)
            {
                [self gestureRecognizerCancel:_reorderGestureRecognizer];
                break;
            }

            // For scrolling while dragging
            _scrollDisplayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(scrollTableWithCell:)];
            [_scrollDisplayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            // Check for the right indexes (between margins of offset
            if (indexPath.row >=_elementsOffset && indexPath.row < [_elements count]+_elementsOffset){

                if (indexPath) {
                    sourceIndexPath = indexPath;

                    id sourceElement = [_elements objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row-_elementsOffset];

                    snapshot = [self createSnapshotForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath withPosition:location];
                }
            } else {
                sourceIndexPath = nil;
                snapshot = nil;
            }
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

            [self calculateScroll:_reorderGestureRecognizer];

            if (sourceIndexPath != nil && indexPath.row >=_elementsOffset && indexPath.row < [_elements count]+_elementsOffset){
                [self updateSnapshotWithPosition:location];

                // Is destination valid and is it different from source?
                if (indexPath && ![indexPath isEqual:sourceIndexPath]) {
                    if (indexPath.row - sourceIndexPath.row <= 1){

                        id sourceElement = [_elements objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row-_elementsOffset];
                        id targetElement = [_elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-_elementsOffset];

                        sourceIndexPath = [self exchangeElement:sourceElement byElement:targetElement];
                    }

                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            // For scrolling while dragging
            [_scrollDisplayLink invalidate];
            _scrollDisplayLink = nil;
            _scrollRate = 0;


            // Check if it is the last element
            if (sourceIndexPath != nil){
                id element;
                if (indexPath.row <=_elementsOffset){
                    element = [_elements firstObject];
                } else if (indexPath.row > [_elements count]-1+_elementsOffset){
                    element = [_elements lastObject];
                } else {
                    element = [_elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-_elementsOffset];
                }  
            }

        }

        default: {
            // Clean up.
            [self deleteSnapshotForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

            [appDelegate startTimer];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

***gestureRecognizerCancel:***

It is use to cancel gesture recognition to finish the reorder action.

```
-(void) gestureRecognizerCancel:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{ // See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4167471/143378
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

***scrollTableWithCell:***

The method it is called to make scrolling movement when you are in the limits of the table (up and down)

```
- (void)scrollTableWithCell:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = _reorderGestureRecognizer;
    const CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:_tableView];

    CGPoint currentOffset = _tableView.contentOffset;
    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(currentOffset.x, currentOffset.y + _scrollRate * 10);

    if (newOffset.y < -_tableView.contentInset.top)
    {
        newOffset.y = -_tableView.contentInset.top;
    }
    else if (_tableView.contentSize.height + _tableView.contentInset.bottom < _tableView.frame.size.height)
    {
        newOffset = currentOffset;
    }
    else if (newOffset.y > (_tableView.contentSize.height + _tableView.contentInset.bottom) - _tableView.frame.size.height)
    {
        newOffset.y = (_tableView.contentSize.height + _tableView.contentInset.bottom) - _tableView.frame.size.height;
    }

    [_tableView setContentOffset:newOffset];

    if (location.y >= 0 && location.y <= _tableView.contentSize.height + 50)
    {

        [self updateSnapshotWithPosition:location];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self getCellIndexPathWithPoint:location];

        // CHeck if element is between offset limits.
        if (![indexPath isEqual:sourceIndexPath] &&
            indexPath.row >= _elementsOffset &&
            indexPath.row - _elementsOffset < [_elements count] &&
            sourceIndexPath.row >= _elementsOffset &&
            sourceIndexPath.row - _elementsOffset < [_elements count])
        {
            id sourceElement = [_elements objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row-_elementsOffset];
            id targetElement = [_elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-_elementsOffset];
            [self exchangeElement:sourceElement byElement:targetElement];
            sourceIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }
}
```

**B. Snapshot management**

***createSnapshotForCellAtIndexPath:withPosition***

Method that creates a snapshot (a image copy) of the cell you are moving

```
-(UIView *)createSnapshotForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withPosition:(CGPoint)location{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Take a snapshot of the selected row using helper method.
    snapshot = [self customSnapshoFromView:cell];

    // Add the snapshot as subview, centered at cell's center...
    __block CGPoint center = cell.center;
    snapshot.center = center;
    snapshot.alpha = 0.0;

    [_tableView addSubview:snapshot];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        // Offset for gesture location.
        center.y = location.y;
        snapshot.center = center;
        snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
        snapshot.alpha = 0.98;
        cell.alpha = 0.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        cell.hidden = YES;
    }];

    return snapshot;
}
```

***customSnapshoFromView:***

Returns a customized snapshot of a given view. */

```
- (UIView *)customSnapshoFromView:(UIView *)inputView {

    // Make an image from the input view.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [inputView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Create an image view.
    snapshot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    snapshot.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    snapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
    snapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0, 0.0);
    snapshot.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    snapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;

    return snapshot;
}
```

***updateSnapshotWithPosition:***

Given a CGPoint, it changes the snapshot position to show the cell you are moving in the right place of the _tableView

```
-(void)updateSnapshotWithPosition:(CGPoint)location{
    CGPoint center = snapshot.center;
    center.y = location.y;
    snapshot.center = center;
}
```

***deleteSnapshotForRowAtIndexPath:***

When dragging finishes, you need to delete the snapshot from the _tableView

```
-(void)deleteSnapshotForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
    cell.hidden = NO;
    cell.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        snapshot.center = cell.center;
        snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        snapshot.alpha = 0.0;
        cell.alpha = 1.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [snapshot removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

***calculateScroll***

```
-(void)calculateScroll:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    const CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:_tableView];

    CGRect rect = _tableView.bounds;
    // adjust rect for content inset as we will use it below for calculating scroll zones
    rect.size.height -= _tableView.contentInset.top;

    //[self updateCurrentLocation:gestureRecognizer];

    // tell us if we should scroll and which direction
    CGFloat scrollZoneHeight = rect.size.height / 6;
    CGFloat bottomScrollBeginning = _tableView.contentOffset.y + _tableView.contentInset.top + rect.size.height - scrollZoneHeight;
    CGFloat topScrollBeginning = _tableView.contentOffset.y + _tableView.contentInset.top  + scrollZoneHeight;

    // we're in the bottom zone
    if (location.y >= bottomScrollBeginning)
    {
        _scrollRate = (location.y - bottomScrollBeginning) / scrollZoneHeight;
    }
    // we're in the top zone
    else if (location.y <= topScrollBeginning)
    {
        _scrollRate = (location.y - topScrollBeginning) / scrollZoneHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        _scrollRate = 0;
    }

}
```

**C. How to use it**

In your init method, assign a gesture recognizer to the table view. Assign as action the method `longPressGestureRecognized:` as follows:

```
    _reorderGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognized:)];

    [_tableView addGestureRecognizer:_reorderGestureRecognizer];
```

Declare the variables you will need to use the above code explained

```
@implementation YourClassName{

    CADisplayLink *_scrollDisplayLink;
    CGFloat _scrollRate;
    UIView *snapshot; // A snapshot of the row user is moving.
    NSIndexPath *sourceIndexPath; // Initial index path, where gesture begins.
}
```

And that's everything you will need to solve the problem I had.

Comment: can you share all source code of your view controller or can you show what is '_elementsOffset'(how it is calculated) and other helper methods e.g. 'calculateScroll'

Comment: elementsOffset is optional, you can use it if your table have elements in the top of your table that you wanted to lock. I have share in this repository my class https://github.com/enrimr/EMRReorderTableCells if you have any question, don't hesitate to ask me ;) Hope it can help you!

Comment: @EnriMR can you help out on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72259537/drag-drop-table-view-cell-has-weired-buggy-animation-while-dragging-cell

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a way to render tableview cells by long pressing them.
And I found a repository for that purpose. If you don't mind putting 3rd party library to your project check it out! :)

[LPRTableView](https://github.com/nicolasgomollon/LPRTableView)

Personally I use this code for my app Cheetah Note. and they are working like a charm! Highly recommended!

Comment: I'm working with Objective-C but in the description of that repository, I have found that https://github.com/bvogelzang/BVReorderTableView .I'm going to test it

Comment: I can't compile that project

Comment: Yes I'm sorry to hear that.. The repository haven't been updated for so long. You may use LPRTableView with this tutorial https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html In the tutorial you would find a way to import swift class to object file :)

Answer (score 0):

Using option one try to scroll to the dragged cell position - 1 when the dragged cell is at the top:

```
NSArray *indexVisibles = [_tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSInteger indexForObject = [indexVisibles indexOfObject:indexPath];
if (indexForObject == 0){
     [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForCellBefore
                                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                                  animated:YES];
}
```

To smoothly scroll the tableview use the following snippet:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0 animations: ^{
     [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForCellBefore atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
 } completion: ^(BOOL finished){
 }];
```

Of-course you need to modify that to work when you scroll down.

Comment: It doesn't help me because the animation for `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:Animated` is very strong, I would like to scroll the UITableView smoothly

Comment: Yes, it solves one of my problems that is how to maintain the cell you are dragging in the position 0 when you drag it to the top, but the movement is not smooth

Comment: thats what I expected. just to confirm it. I will try to check for the other problem.

Comment: I've tried that `if (indexForObject == 0 && indexPath.row > 0){
                            [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:0]
                                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                                      animated:YES];
                        }` I don't know the difference for UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle and UITableViewScrollPositionTop. But with middle, it goes pretty fast (something that I neither want) But it's more real animation

Comment: Please check this repository hope this is work for you. github.com/hpique/HPReorderTableView